# Woocommerce downloadable file dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

i'm trying to create a custom woocommerce management here, i have the idea about how i want it to work, but i'm a bit confuse about how to start doing that, let me explain:

I have woocommerce installed with 1 product only, it's about photo customization, so customer will buy a customized photo with custom message and send to friends.

Then i'll have a user role in wordpress that's responsible for the photo customization, so what i'm trying to do is:

1- Customer place an order and pay
2- Woocommerce generate a new order ID
3- I need to be able to create an control panel in front end for the user role that'll customize the photo
4- After this customization, the user role (let's call them 'customizers'), they need to be able to upload this photo and attach to the order ID in woocommerce
5- Admin will review this customized photo and if approved, admin will mark the order as complete and customer will be notified about the photo to be downloaded.

So, basically, my only problem it's with the custom control panel for 'customizers' to be able to upload and attach each photo with the order ID.

Any help please?

**EDIT** -> Another solution could be using FTP to upload each photo, so in this case i could somehow attach the order ID with an image like Order_ID.jpg?

Comment: Hi, assuming you already know how to code all your application,  i think admin needs to asigne an order to a customizer, that way, can exist a relation between order and 'customizer'.

Comment: Hey there, so you mean i should create a relation between each order and the 'customizer' in database? Bu the main problem is the photo url to be "updated" in the order and alert the user by email that he can already download his file, i'll dig a bit more here and come up with some code. thanks mate!